# How to tell congestion info on the Bitcoin network?

Tags: transactions, wallet, blockspace-market, trust-wallet

I just tried mining again, using 2Miners and mining Clore.ai, and it can be distributed as BTC.  So finally I had the 50 Clore minimum payout amount at around 2am, and distribution is at 4am everyday.

The amount is only about US$7.

Now it is 7:25am, but my Trust wallet is showing:

> BTC network is currently under congestion

and so I have not got the BTC yet.  I tried to look at the blockchain info on https://www.blockchain.com/ or https://btcscan.org/ , but can't find any congestion notice there.

For privacy reason I won't share my Bitcoin wallet address here.

How do I find the congestion info that the Trust wallet is indicating?

Answer (score 4):

There's really no such thing as "congestion" in Bitcoin. Rather, Bitcoin has a limit on how many transactions it can process, which is 1 block (1 MvB/4 MWU, around 2000-4000 transactions) per 10 minutes. Miners typically select transactions paying the highest feerate to include in the next block, which means a transaction gets included only when it's in the top-paying 1 MvB of unconfirmed transactions. When there are many high-feerate transactions waiting to be confirmed, a transaction paying a low feerate can wait potentially weeks or months (theoretically forever) to get confirmed.

If a service pauses payouts because of "congestion", it simply means they don't want to pay the high fees to get their transactions confirmed and prefer to wait for fees to go down.

You can check [mempool.space](https://mempool.space/) for current fees. The minimum feerate to get into a block has been above 50 sat/vB for a few weeks, which is quite unusual.

Comment: I just got the BTC 10 minutes ago. The instructions on 2Miners says the fees should be only about US$0.20, but I did a calculation... the fees was at least $1.50 to $2.00. It was https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/transactions/btc/9e7da424e744d42c1415ef4b8a8da95aae786e069ca469f1c6bc1ce906c600fa with a fee of $924, for 468 outputs (recipients, I think), so each recipient had to pay about $2.00.  If for $7, the fee was $2, then it is like a 28.5% fee